# Problem loading extjs radiogroup data

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

How do you load data for a radiogroup in extjs, such that the correct radios are checked?

On the [extjs radio/checkbox example page](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/check-radio.html) you will find code like this

```
{
  xtype: 'radiogroup',
  fieldLabel: 'Auto Layout',
  items: [
       {boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 1},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 2, checked: true},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 3},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 4', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 4},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 5', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 5}
   ]
 }
```

I would expect that doing a form.load() with json like `{'rb-auto': 3, …}` would mark Item 3 as checked. This doesn't work.
How could you achieve this effect?

**Answer:** (Zach is correct about extjs 3.1) **My expectation is correct, but only since extjs 3.1 is released recently. Also, you need to set the name on boh the individual radio items as the group itself:**

```
{
  xtype: 'radiogroup',
  fieldLabel: 'Auto Layout',
  name: 'rb-auto',
  items: [
       {boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 1},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 2, checked: true},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 3},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 4', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 4},
       {boxLabel: 'Item 5', name: 'rb-auto', inputValue: 5}
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a solution that was working for extjs 3.0:
http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39161

With 3.1 it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Ok. It seems to me that giving a "name" attribute to radiogroup solves this problem.

Comment: The one from the last page of the thread.
Yes, it was a big flaw and it seems to be corrected right now in extjs 3.1. I just had to find out that it needs the name attr on radiogroup itself apart from naming each radios individually.
Generally speaking - extjs is a great idea but the implementation is poor and undocumented.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It feds out that both the group as the individual items needs to share the same name.

Comment: Doesn't work with ExtJS 4... radiogroup can't use the same name otherwise it crashes during a call to setValue. No solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Using ExtJS 4, the following structure for radio group settings resulting in success for me:

```
{ "data" : 
    [ 
      { "id" : "RadioGroupName",
        "value" : 
            { "RadioGroupName" : "inputValue" }
      },
      { "id" : "RadioGroupName2",
        "value" : 
            { "RadioGroupName2" : "inputValue" }
      }
    ],
  "success" : true
}
```